# WSO2 Identity Server 5.3 AWS clustering mode

Tags: amazon-web-services, wso2-identity-server

Can anyone confirm that the AWS clustering mode provided by the Hazelcast service works fine for IS 5.3?

We have a two documents describing clustering configurations;

[Clustering Identity Server 5.x](https://docs.wso2.com/display/CLUSTER44x/Clustering+Identity+Server+5.1.0%2C+5.2.0+and+5.3.0) which describes and relies upon WKA for service discovery

[Setting up a cluster in AWS mode](https://docs.wso2.com/display/CLUSTER44x/Setting+up+a+Cluster+in+AWS+Mode) which appears to be generic instructions for all products but requires an AWS IAM role to describe instances (probably preferred in our use-case)

Is the AWS mode available for Identity Server or are we restricted to WKA?  It's not clear if the Clustering Identity Server document overrides the more generic cluster document.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes. There are current users who use AWS clustering with WSO2 IS 5.3.0.

[Clustering Identity Server 5.x](https://docs.wso2.com/display/CLUSTER44x/Clustering+Identity+Server+5.1.0%2C+5.2.0+and+5.3.0) is a generic clustering docuement about IS 5.3.0 and does not specific to AWS. Use [Setting up a cluster in AWS mode](https://docs.wso2.com/display/CLUSTER44x/Setting+up+a+Cluster+in+AWS+Mode) for IS AWS clustering which is generic for specified carbon kernel version. Any product runs on top of this kernel version can use this guide.